# How to change android button text color globally in theme

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components, material-components-android

How can I change all my buttons text color?

I know I can set the background color like follows :

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/buttonColor</item>
</style>
```

How can I do this for the button Text?

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023601/android-style-specify-button-color)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
 <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <item name="android:textColor">#yourcolor</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonColor</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/buttonColor</item>
</style>



<style name="ButtonColor" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
   <item name="android:textColor">@color/yourcolor</item>
</style>
```

**android:textColor** This should help you change the text color globally.

Comment: Will this only be for buttons? or `editText` and `textView`

Comment: i have edited the code. this code will only apply for button's. The older one , apply's for all. ThankYou. I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Works, but use `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button` as the parent style for ButtonColor to get Material Design AppCompat style.

Comment: in this answer <item name="android:textColor">#yourcolor</item> seam to not only apply to button but also to everything

Answer (score 17):

With the new [`Theme.MaterialComponents`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#material-components-themes) theme you can define the [**`materialButtonStyle`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Color.md#theming-all-instances-of-one-component) attribute in your app theme, to customize globally the style of all buttons in your app.

```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
       <!-- .... --> 
       <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button</item>
  </style>
```

With

```
<style name="Widget.App.Button" parent="Widget.Material3.Button">
    <!-- button style customization example -->
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Button</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.App.Button</item>
    <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent</item>
</style>
```

Use `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button` as parent if you are using Material2 theme.

If you would like to override only some attributes like colors from the default style use the **`materialThemeOverlay`** attribute.

Something like:

```
  <style name="Widget.App.Button" parent="Widget.Material3.Button">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Button</item>
  </style>

  <style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Button">
    <!-- For filled buttons, your theme's colorPrimary provides the default background color of the component, and -->
    <!--the text color is colorOnPrimary -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_color</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/my_color2</item>
    
  </style>
```

Comment: works like magic.

Answer (score 11):

If you just need to change the text colour of buttons. You can modify the `textAppearanceButton` style attribute of your main theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/buttonColor</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceButton">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button.Custom</item>
</style>
```

And declare your new textAppearance style as follows

```
<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button.Custom">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/mycustomcolor</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 11):

For anyone that stumbles onto this, I recommend checking out a similar question about [Material Design Button Styles.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36666660/2461717) With a theme, your "accent color" will be used to color your button.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since MaterialComponents Buttons use colorPrimary by default you can simply set colorOnPrimary in your theme when using Theme.MaterialComponents.Light, don't know if it's the same with Material3.

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Base.Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
        <!-- Customize your light theme here. -->
        ...
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/colorOnPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Base.Theme.MyApplication" />
</resources>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just using `AppCompatButton` by setting this attribute :

```
"app:backgroundTint="@color/wildberries"
```

And make sure your activity extends AppCompatActivity. I just use it in my project. It works like a charm in both 5.X and pre-5.X.

Comment: This doesn't change the colour of the buttons' text.

Answer (score -3):

```
<Button  
     app:backgroundTint="#fece2f" //any color
 />
```

This is best way if you don't want it to be defined globally

Comment: This doesn't change the colour of the buttons' text.