# How to change to text color of all the button in my app?

Tags: android, android-button, android-theme, android-styles

How can i change the text color of all the button in my app ? right now the only think that work is to do :

```
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"> 

    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>

  </style>
```

but i m a little worried to use `android:textColor` who seam to not only impact the button

I try this but it's didn't work :

```
  <style name="BBButtonColor" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
  </style> 

  <style name="BBButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
  </style> 

  <style name="BBBorderlessButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
  </style> 


  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"> 

    <item name="android:textAppearanceButton">@style/BBButtonColor</item> 
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/BBButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:borderlessButtonStyle">@style/BBBorderlessButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#ff0000</item>

  </style>
```

It's mostly the color of button inside popup dialog that i want to change

Comment: did you check [How to change android button text color globally in theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261421/how-to-change-android-button-text-color-globally-in-theme)?

Comment: I think this previous answer properly fits your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261421/how-to-change-android-button-text-color-globally-in-theme/36261451

Comment: @RaviRupareliya: I already read this question, but nothing in it work for me :(

Comment: @RiccardoCoppola I also already read this question, but nothing in it work for me :(

Comment: @loki can you please elaborate the issue by adding some files like `styles.xml`, `AndroidManifest.xml`, one of the `layout.xml`, etc. This will help us narrow down the issue.

Comment: @MohitAjwani done, I just updated the question

Comment: @loki I have submitted a solution. Please check and let me know if it works.

Comment: @MohitAjwani: no it's didn't help :(

Answer (score 1):

Loki, you can try this. This should change the color of all buttons in your app.

```
<style name="BBButtonColor" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

You were trying to use `@android:style/Widget.Button`, instead use `android:Widget.Button` and check. Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonColor</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorname</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonColor" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorname</item>
</style>
```

and/change this line in Manifest file :

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Base
```

Answer (score -1):

You should create new style for buttons, something like that:

```
<style name="optionsButton">
        <item name="android:layout_width">70dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    </style>
```

Now you can set this style for every button you want in layout xml, for example:

```
                <Button
                android:id="@+id/payCashBtn"
                style="@style/optionsButton"
                android:text="Cash" />
```

You can see I set layout_width and height in style, so all my buttons which use this style will have same parameters, but you can set different values for every button, or create multiple styles if you used it more than once. I hope it will help you.

Comment: no, i need to do it globally. I don't use any layout in my app, everything come from material design