# Set button's background from android attributes based on API version

Tags: android

In my app I want all buttons to have the same background.

For API 21 and newer `?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless`

For older APIs `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground`

How do I set button's background in XML so that it references correct drawable based on android version?

Answer (score 4):

Inside `styles.xml` in `res/values` folder create a theme for application:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
</style>
```

Inside `styles.xml` in `res/values-v21` folder create a theme for application:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>
</style>
```

Apply a theme to application in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
(...)
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
(...)
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution works but I wonder if it's possible to do the same thing without using styles. A better solution for me would be if I could somehow wrap android drawables into my own drawables, put them in drawable, drawable-v21 folders and then just set background directly on the view?

Comment: Declare drawables  with the same name in `res/drawable` and `res/drawable-v21` and point `android:background` of Button to that drawable? I am not really sure if that is what you mean.

Comment: Yes, but I want my drawable to use `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground`. How do I do that? What type of drawable do I need? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Create two style. Reference: [Creating styles-v21.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465064/creating-styles-v21-xml)

After first step: Set ButtonStyle 
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14033420/7001152