# How do you apply a button style to all buttons in an Android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, material-components-android

I've created a brand new app using the basic activity. I want to change the colour of all buttons (from the default primary colour of purple to a custom non-primary colour of green). Here's my themes.xml:

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/ButtonColour</item>

        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyApplication.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ButtonColour" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
        <item name="backgroundTint">#689f38</item>
        <item name="rippleColor">#c5e1a5</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.MyApplication.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="Theme.MyApplication.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

where I apply the `ButtonColour` style, as defined in the android dev docs here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#Widgets
When the app is ran with that custom style to change the buttons to green, the buttons are still the default primary colour.

I've read other questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261421/how-to-change-android-button-text-color-globally-in-theme), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023601/android-style-specify-button-color), and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410836/how-do-i-apply-a-style-to-all-buttons-of-an-android-application)) but none of their solutions helps either. Does anyone have any guidance on how this can properly be done?

Comment: If you're using MaterialComponents (which your theme is) then you probably want to set `materialButtonStyle` instead. The Material Design docs are probably more useful to you, it has its own theming system: https://material.io/develop/android/theming/color (scroll down to the Theming All Instances bit)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use materialButtonStyle instead of buttonStyle.

```
<item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/ButtonColour</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<style name="ButtonColour" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
```

to

```
<style name="ButtonColour" parent="Theme.MyApplication">
```

In Button:

```
<Button style="@style/ButtonColour"
```

as you have already used materialtheme as parent theme for app. Button, by default inherits the material theme properties.

Answer (score -1):

you can create a new layout resource file inside the drawable folder in the resources and its gonna be a shape

inside this XML file, you're gonna be able to edit your button style like so:`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<solid
    android:color="@color/antique_white"/>

</shape>
```

`
you can change the color inside <solid.
now, you need to use this XML file as a background for all your buttons as so:
let's say you named the XML file button_style

```
android:background="@drawable/button_style"
```

now you can just edit the XML file and the changes would apply to all you buttons.

Comment: This isn't really a fix.. the proper way to set the background colour is by using the backgroundTint attribute, not just setting the background picture to a solid colour.. a proper fix has been given in the comments of the question.